# Jquery click on a[href="#open-site"] doesnt work with link

Tags: jquery, html, function, navigation, click

I have a navigation that looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html#open-site">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#open-site">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="test.html#open-site">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

When i click on #open-site, a  show up.
If im on index.html and i click as an example on the second link without the "index.html" everything works fine and the div shows up.

but if im on index.html and i click the first link nothing happens. The site wont reload and the click-function isn´t triggered.

My jquery code looks like this

```
jQuery('a[href="#open-site"]').click(function () {
    jQuery('#content').animate({"left": "0px"});
})
```

What i want is that if im on index.html and i click 'index.html#open-site' is that the page wont reload but the click function is triggered and the div shows up.

If im on a other subpage like test.html and i click 'index.html#open-site' , index.html will load and the div immediately shows up.

Comment: Dont use an Anchor for this. You can set ur own Attribute. Something like this:

jQuery('a[yourATTR="open-site"]').click(function () {
    jQuery('#content').animate({"left": "0px"});
})

Answer (score 0):

You should have a selector for each option.

```
<ul>
    <li id="site1"><a href="index.html#open-site">Test</a></li>
    <li id="site2"><a href="#open-site">Test</a></li>
    <li id="site3"><a href="test.html#open-site">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then you try to trigger an event on these selectors.

Comment: Yes, i thought the same but there is one problem.

I dont have a single div for every menu item. Instead i have one div called "page" in which the content is loaded over the cms. 

So if i do it your way i must find a way over the cms to add an id or a class to the page div regarding on which subpage i am and i must define a jquery function for every subpage. That is not very dynamically.

If the link i click euqals the page im at, i just want to trigger the jquery function and not reload the page. If its another subpage the site will reload and div will show up.That already works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood that you want. And hope it help you.

It searches elements in strict accordance selectors.

```
jQuery('a[href="#open-site"]')
```

It returns only elements where href = #open-site

To find all elements with same parameter but not in the strict accordance like the example above, you want to filter all elements to find necessary elements.
My code example does not ideal but it is an example what you can do.

```
jQuery('a').each(function(index) {
    // we search the links with param in href attr from all links to attach the function
    if (jQuery(this).attr('href').search('#open-site') !== -1) {
        jQuery(this).click(function (e) {
            // e = event
            // e.preventDefault stops default behavior (changing location)
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery('#content').animate({"left": "0px"});
        });
    }
});
```

An example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6wpxh6us/)

Comment: Thank you! This is almost what i want to do. But i want this only to happen if the link that is clicked equals the current page. So what i need is on more if query that compares the clicked link to the current page. If it quals then do e.prevenDefault(); if not then redirect to the clicked link. The problem with that is that i dont know how to get only the "index.html" or "index" part from a whole url like this "www.x.com/index.html". It also has to be dynamic because i dont know the final url.

Comment: Sorry for late answer :)
You can check url and link's href to decide stop the event or not.

Comment: For example
`if (jQuery().attr('href').split('#')[0] === '' || window.location.href.search(jQuery().attr('href').split('#')[0]) > -1) {
 // preventDefault & animate
}`
This check should to wrap the event stop and the animate function